# How to delete target using shell script in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Suppose I have added two target in Xcode:

1. Target of application.
2. iMessage Extension target.
3. Keyboard Extension target.

I want to delete particular target through BUILDER using shell script based on certain condition.

How can I do so that Xcode build succeed with target?

[image: With iMessage Target]

[image: Without iMessage Target]

Comment: what's BUILDER ? can you please explain more your usecase ?

Comment: xcproj  is an open source tool to manipulate xcode projects, it may be helpful.
https://github.com/0xced/xcproj

Comment: BUILDER is necessary because build can be created using JENKINS and customer can select that which TARGET should include in bundle.

Comment: Want to check if you found a solution for this. Also can you elaborate more on the builder